# Non-Asynchronous code in Javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Coming from sysadmin background, I'm trying to use node for some scripting tasks. (Parsing some text, pushing into `MongoDB` etc.)

I've been hacking at this for hours and this is the way I could make it print 1-2-3 with 2 seconds apart. Else all would be printed at once.

I've been reading about `Promises` and `Async/await` but I want to understand the core concept before I move on to those abstractions.

What is happening here? (Forgive the bad pattern)

```js
"use strict"

//let arg = process.argv.slice(2)
let arg = [1,2,3]

function d(fn){
    return setTimeout(fn,2000)
}

let a = x=>{
    let b = x=>{
        let c = x=>{
            d(y=>console.log(arg[2]))
        }
        d(
            y=>{
                console.log(arg[1])
                return c()
            }
        )
    }
    d(
        y=>{console.log(arg[0])
            return b()
        }
    )
}

a()
```

If this were to be written in cleaner way but without `Promises` or `Async/await`, how would it be?

Comment: actually that is exactly the reason the promisses and async/await specifications were written. to get rid of this "callback hell"

Comment: http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html

Comment: `without Promises or Async/await` With node.js now naively supporting Promise / async / await.  Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @user2520818 I appreciate the candid feedback. I just want to understand some of what is going on under the hood without going in too deep where I will be lost :)

Comment: @Keith I would use it of course, I'm running latest node.js anyway. This is just for learning, even if I won't do it the callback hell way.

Comment: well, then `setTimeout` works simply like: here have a function, wait this given time and then run it (call it back). and you can nest them like. hey settimeout call my function, which it self is another settimeout, and that one calls another timeout.

Comment: In that case understanding callbacks on it's own isn't too complicated.  Your basically passing a completion function.  As in your example with the setTimeout this is passed to fn.  The fn function is then called when complete.

Comment: Do you just want to print after waiting two seconds?

Comment: Also the title is wrong: you don't want to block execution for logging - and for sysadmin, you definitely don't want to block execution for reading a file! Learn `async/await` and `util.promisify` as the other posters note.

Answer (score 0):

this way you could write it not nested.

```
function fn0() {
  console.log(arg[0]);
  // wait another 2s then call fn1
  setTimeout(fn1, 2000);
}

function fn1() {
  console.log(arg[1]);
  // wait again 2s then call fn2
  setTimeout(fn2, 2000);
}

function fn2() {
  console.log(arg[2]);
}

// wait 2s then call fn0
setTimeout(fn0, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using a recursive call to avoid nested callbacks. This works with any size array.

```
let arg = [1, 2, 3];

function next(i) {
  if (arg[i]) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(arg[i]),
      next(i+1);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

next(0);
```